# System not supported exception when using response.outputstream.write

Tags: c#, httpresponse

I'm working on a web application that uses a control to get the file from its location and returns some bytes. I now want to pass these bytes to the next page using server.transfer. So I'm calling response.outputstream.write() and passing in the bytes.

However when I'm debugging the application I get a 'System.NotSupportedException'
exception message and the length and size is empty. Any ideas what could be causing this issue?

```
file = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filepath);
Response.OutputStream.Write(file, 0, file.Length);
Server.Transfer(URL, true);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like that :

```
Page.Response.Clear();
Page.Response.Buffer = false;
Page.Server.ScriptTimeout = 3000;

Page.Response.ContentType = sContentType;
Page.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + sFilename + "\"");

FileInfo oFileInfo = new FileInfo(sSourceFullPath);
long lfull_size = oFileInfo.Length;
oFileInfo = null;

Page.Response.AddHeader("Content-length", lfull_size.ToString());

Page.Response.WriteFile(sSourceFullPath);
Page.Response.End();
```

I'm not sure where is your problem.

Comment: I was able to solve the issue I was having by making a WebRequest to the aspx page and then using Response.OutputStream.

Answer (score 0):

Just because this is something I ran into just now. Make sure you do not put

```
Writer.Flush();
```

before

```
OutputStream.Write();
```

I made this mistake, and it gave me the same error as posted in this problem. Hope this helps someone.